# psql extra command line argument

Tags: postgresql, psql

Can someone tell me why I get the error extra command line argument here?  When I use -f and give it the full path to the sql file it works fine.  I would like to use a relative path instead so I was trying to use the \ir command.

```
psql -c \c postgresql://docker:1234/nbt?ssl=true -U admin -v username='user73291' -v recipeId=2 -c \ir '../../../resources/sql/myfile.sql'
```

Error:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "../../../resources/sql/myfile.sql" ignored
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ir"
LINE 1: ir
    ^
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\i` is a meta-command to be used in the psql command line, not in the shell command line. What is the problem with `-f`?

Comment: I thought I read that you couldn't do relative path with -f.  If I can, i'll give that a try?